# Android Studio "Search Everywhere" feature not searching in code files

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

"Search everywhere" feature in Android Studio is not finding strings in code files.  Why is it not able to find a string literal or a variable name?

Irrefutable photographic evidence:

[image: Irrefutable photographic evidence]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Search Everywhere" is generally looking for the following things:

- Class/Module names
- Function names
- File names
- Database names
- Configuration options named similarly

It's not suitable for finding a string literal or a variable based in hundreds of lines of code which may have similar literals available to it.

For that, I'd recommend either "Find in Path", or "Symbol", which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: Rather than using find in Path, you could also use the Symbol... search (CMD-ALT-O on a mac) to find symbols (variables, method names, etc) with the given name.

Comment: @emerssso:  Thanks for that tip - I usually forget about that option.  I've incorporated it into my answer.